# Using Apple Keyboard OSX way in Linux Destop

Tags: gnome, keyboard-shortcuts, macintosh

Is it possible (using Debian and latest Gnome, but any distro/DE applies) to use Standard Apple Keyboard OSX Way? E.g. using `Cmd+Key` for UI actions (`Cmd+C` for Copy, etc...), but use `Ctrl+Key` in terminal emulator (`Ctrl+C` to abort task)

Main goal is to use `Cmd+C` (abort) and `Ctrl+C` (copy) simultaneously in terminal emulator

I can switch `Cmd` and `Ctrl` completely, but that's not an option

Comment: See this thread on [askubuntu.com](https://askubuntu.com/questions/131900/how-do-i-switch-the-command-key-and-control-key-on-a-macbook-pro).

Answer (score 1):

You will generally need to configure such hotkeys on a per-application basis.

Some desktop environments (notably KDE) allow setting standard hotkeys that apply to all applications.

You can configure which keyboard keys map to which X11 modifier keys by configuring XKB, or using your desktop environment's graphical configuration tool.